# How to replace all non alpha characters (digits and special characters) from std::string with a space

Tags: c++, string, stl

I am quite new to STL in C++ and am not able to get a proper output even after hours.

```
int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello8$World";
    replace(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isdigit, " ");
    replace(str.begin(), str.end(), ::ispunct, " ");
    return 0;
}
```

I would have been very happy if the above worked but it doesn't.

Comment: You can use a `stringstream` and add characters back in after checking their integer values.

Comment: I would really love to see a working example.thank you

Comment: @abhilash You can not accept all three answers :D

Comment: oops.I guess the 1st one gets accepted :)

Comment: _@abhilashpoojary_ 1. You should improve your question providing a [MCVE] and show all the error messages verbatim. 2. May be you've been too fast with accepting, @skypjack's answer looks most promising for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of function that uses a predicate is [`std::replace_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) and you want to replace characters, so `' '`, not `" "` - this is `char const*`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello8$World";
    std::replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isdigit, ' ');
    std::replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(), ::ispunct, ' ');
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have `std::isdigit` and I have `::isdigit`. Interesting.

Comment: Yes interesting, when I remove `std::` [it actually works](http://ideone.com/f5nzs4)

Comment: It is because `isdigit` and `ispunct` come from C. So, to allow for backwards compatibility, C++ defines it at a global namespace level (that is what the `::` means at the beginning) and does not put it in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 5):

All in one with a *lambda function*, more *C++14*-ish:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::string str = "Hello8$World";

    std::replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](auto ch) {
        return ::isdigit(ch) || ::ispunct(ch);
    }, ' ');

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This way you won't iterate twice over the string.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong function.  `std::replace` takes two iterators an old value and a new value.  `std::replace_if` takes two iterators a function and a new value.  You also need to use `' '` not `" "` as the the type the string iterator points to is a char not a string.  If you change it to

```
replace_if(str.begin(),str.end(),::isdigit,' ');
replace_if(str.begin(),str.end(),::ispunct,' ');
```

It works just fine([Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c2098a2c85603ca)).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Check my example.  You are using `std::isdigit` which is not the same as `::isdigit`.

Comment: What makes the difference? I just noticed it works without `std::`

Comment: It is because `isdigit` and `ispunct` come from C. So, to allow for backwards compatibility, C++ defines it at a global namespace level (that is what the `::` means at the beginning) and does not put it in the `std` namespace.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the global one is the C function which has one parameter.  the C++ standard version has a locale parameter in addition to the int so it cannot be resolved in the template parameter as it expects a Unary function.

Comment: Oh, there's this [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isdigit).

Comment: @callyalater That is not the problem.  See my comment to πάνταῥεῖ on what the issue really is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `replace_if` function in this case because you are checking a condition. [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) has a good explanation of this. The last two parameters of `replace_if` are the UnaryPredicate (a function that takes one parameter and returns `true` or `false`) and the underlying type of object at each location in the iterator (which for strings is a `char`, not a string).

```
int main()
{
    std::string str="Hello8$World";
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    std::replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isdigit, ' ');
    std::replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(), ::ispunct, ' ');
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```